# Javascript/JQuery guessing game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's a JSfiddle of a guessing game I'm making: http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/13/ 
So far everything is working great, but the part that displays the remaining guesses isn't working the way I want it to. It starts out at 3 and goes down by one each time you have an incorrect guess, which is what I want, but once you run out of guesses I want you to revert back to level one and have the remaining guesses go back to 3 since you are starting over. It successfully starts the game over, but the display of the count gets stuck at 0 (even though it's actually back to 3). I also want the displayed guesses remaining to go back up to 3 after you get a correct guess (while moving up a level), but it doesn't. Can anyone help me fix this? Here is the actual code in question:

HTML:

```
<p id="result">Guess a color.</p>
<p>Remaining guesses: <span id="guesses">3</span></p>
<h2>Level <span id="level">1</span></h2>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
 function correct(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are correct! Guess another color.";
  level++;
  reset(); 
 }

function incorrect(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, you are incorrect.";
  guesses--;
  document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guesses;
   if (guesses == 0){
     level = 1;
      reset();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Guess a color";      
   }

  }

function reset(){
  $(".box").animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  guesses = 3;
  temp = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
}

function rand(){
  temp = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  $("div.box").click(function() {
      if (temp == $(this).data("id")) {
          correct();
      } else {
          $(this).animate({"opacity": "0.25"}, "slow");
          incorrect();
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
   document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guesses;
```

into your reset function.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @user1157541 since you are using jquery use `$('#guesses').text(guesses)`